# How to show loading message in same Div where result shows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loading

I have a request like this to send mail after form submit.

```
post_data = {'userName':name, 'userEmail':email, 'userMessage':message};

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  

            //load json data from server and output message     
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<p style="color:red;" class="help-block">Oh no!! Error occured</p>';
            }else{
                output = '<p style="color:green;" class="help-block">'+response.text+'</p>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#contact_form input').val(''); 
                $('#contact_form textarea').val(''); 
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
```

After getting response I will show message in this div

```
<div id="result" class="col-md-8"></div>
```

Now I need to show a loading message in this same div while ajax request is processing. How to do that? I have seen many answers but nothing related to this type of query

Comment: When the call is fired, update the html of the element to say loading, on success remove this message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
$("#result").append("Loading Data...");

 //Ajax post data to server

        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){ 

         $("#result").html(response);

         }
```